# Bitcoind in a Windows Azure Worker Role

Tags: bitcoind, windows

I want to have a Bitcoind node running in Azure. Obviously there are storage requirements from storing the blockchain, so is Bitcoind a candidate for a worker role? Or would I be better off sticking to a VM?

Comment: interestingly enough, I'm trying to get microsoft to release a "bitcoin node as a service"... with all their bullshit blockchain partnership Azure showed no love for bitcoin.

Comment: @NicolasDorier Isn't that what this is? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/bitcore-centos-vm/

Comment: bitcore is a blockexplorer by Bitpay, what I would like is just a Bitcoin node with the blockchain pre indexed, without shitware on it. :p

The blockchain being updated something like every month so if I want more nodes, I don't have to wait a week to get it operative. Also with endpoint where I can communicate with RPC. (internal)


I did not tried this VM so let me know if it still works well for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a worker role as a possible candidate primarily because of the complexity involved. Other than storage and unless I am missing something (just used worker roles once in the past) you will also have deployment difficulties, which will have to be repeated with every bitcoin upgrade. I do not see what you will gain using a worker role anyway (in the context of bitcoind). (?)

So, if the choice is between the two I would say stick with the VM.

Note that Azure also provides an option to easily install a full bitcoin core node using [bitcore](https://bitcore.io/) in a CentOS VM. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/bitcore-centos-vm/) for details; it offers some extras that might interest you.

Comment: I've run bitcoind happily in Azure VMs before - can you elaborate on why you don't think a VM is a candidate?

Comment: Apologies @Avram; you are right. The answer was written in a hurry. I do not see it as a candidate for a worker role primarily because of the complexity, but that is not the case for just installing in a VM. I will update my answer.